React Three Fiber - Outline post processing issue
I have an issue with outline post processing. I would like to apply outline on planes when user moves the cursor over the planes. It is almost working but there is a small issue

When the mouse is over the selected mesh the outline is visible but the bottom and edges where is another planes the outlines is barely visible.
The outline should be visible around the planes whatever there is a plane next to it.
I used r3f and react-postprocessing to achieve this.

I made GroupWithPointer component which is changes the cursor to pointer.

import { Select } from "@react-three/postprocessing";

const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

<group
  {...groupProps}
  onPointerEnter={(e) => { // handle mosue event }}
  onPointerLeave={(e) => { // handle mouse event }}
>
  <Select enabled={isHovered}>
    {children}
  </Select>
</group>


Wrap Plane within GroupWithPointer

import { EffectComposer, Outline, Selection } from "@react-three/postprocessing";
import { Plane } from "@react-three/drei";

const backgroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: "#D9D9D9"});

<Selection>
  <EffectComposer>
    <Outline
      visibleEdgeColor={0xff0202}
      hiddenEdgeColor={0xff0202}
    />
  </EffectComposer>

  <GroupWithPointer position={[0, 1.8, 0]}>
    <Plane args={[3, 5]} material={backgroundMaterial} />
  </GroupWithPointer>
  <GroupWithPointer position={[2.5, 0.8, 0]}>
    <Plane args={[2, 3]} material={backgroundMaterial} />
  </GroupWithPointer>
</Selection>

Here is a codesandbox demo which presents a similar issue.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.
